# merge rows in pandas with empty values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, rows

I have following table.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 |  |  |  |  |
|  | value1 |  |  |  |
|  |  | value2 |  |  |
|  |  |  | value3 |  |
|  |  |  |  | value4 |
| key2 |  |  |  |  |

I want to merge rows in the way it shows normal table

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| key2 | value6 | value7 | value8 | value9 |

how is that possible with pandas?

EDIT:
As in comments mentioned, I upload the dataset [here](https://share.accerun.com/filebrowser/share/FwHpHMmj).

the dataset is some multiple choice questions and answers, some of the questions are multiple lines (rows) and I have to merge these rows first.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ideally provide a DataFrame constructor of your input

Comment: it's just a csv file.
Nothing special.

Comment: Then provide the exact CSV as text, the current format is ambiguous

Comment: uploaded the csv file and it's ready to download.